# How can I read write edit pptx/docx/xlsx files using PHP?

Tags: php, powerpoint, docx, xlsx

Is there a library extension available for efficiently handling pptx/docx/xlsx files using PHP? As of now I am more interested in PPTX files.

Answer (score 12):

As per what i know, those file formats docx,xlsx,pptx are just zip files. 
they belong to Office Open XML (OOXML) standard.

In PHP we have this library for manipulating this type of zip documents:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

You can find all documentation about this ooxml standard here:
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

The best way to test the structure of these ooxml file is to change the file 
extension to .zip, and the extract it out to find out what are inside.

If you don't want to build your own library for processing ooxml files,
you can refer to a related question here for more info:
[PHP OOXML Libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147280/php-ooxml-libraries)

As i read from the related stackoverflow question mentioned above, 
you can use the phpdocx, or somewhat other called PHPWord.

Hope this may clarify some steps to help get your wants done

Answer (score 3):

There is no one library that can handle all three formats, but there are individual libraries that can read and/or write the individual formats.

- [PHPPowerpoint](http://www.phppowerpoint.net) can write, but not
  read, pptx files
- [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com) can write, but not read, docx files
- [PHPLiveDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) can write (and I believe also reads) docx files
- [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) can read and write xlsx files

Answer (score 2):

You can build docx/xlsx/pptx documents from templates using the [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) PHP tool.

The version currently in development will improve the support of XLSX.

Comment: Looks like it edits without effects other data like charts... great recommendation :)

Answer (score 2):

here is the working example that can read only docx file.

```
<?php
    $filename = "file.docx"; // or /var/www/html/file.docx 

    $content = read_file_docx($filename); 
    if($content !== false) {
        echo nl2br($content); 
    }  
    else {
        echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.'; 
    }

    function read_file_docx($filename){ 

        $striped_content = ''; 
        $content = ''; 

        if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;  

        $zip = zip_open($filename);

        if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false; 

        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) { 

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue; 

            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue; 

            $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry)); 

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry); 
        }// end while 

        zip_close($zip); 

        //echo $content; 

        //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);  

        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content); 
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content); 
        $striped_content = strip_tags($content); 

        return $striped_content; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lots of `<br>`! Seems you forgot to remove br while copy pasting.

Comment: This is plagiarism. the code is a simple copy/paste from http://www.blogs.zeenor.com/it/read-ms-word-docx-ms-word-2007-file-document-using-php.html.  no credits to the author.

Answer (score 0):

I never used those and their documentation is lacking, but you could try with the [.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dotnet.php) and [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) libraries if your server is running on a Windows platform.