# Read .pptx file using PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone knows how to read pptx file in php.

Or

Is there any php library/demo which can read text data from pptx file using php?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you have http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php that belongs to the OOXML

Answer (score 1):

Read this carefully, [how can I read write edit pptx/docx/xlsx files using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562345/how-can-i-read-write-edit-pptx-docx-xlsx-files-using-php)

Note that .pptx is actually a zip file